# How to get state of KafkaStream from a KStream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an application that consumes streams of data generated by mysql binlog. This is the relevant part of my code.

```java
KStream<GenericRecord,mysql.x.Envelope> xStream = builder.stream(sourceTopicName,
                    Consumed.with(XSerde.getGenericKeySerde(), XSerde.getEnvelopeSerde()));
```

For some health checking purposes I need to be able to get the state of the KafkaStream. Is it running, pending shutdown...
I couldn't find any relation between KafkaStream and KStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get it after building the StreamsBuilder, and using it to start the application. The health is for the entire application, not individual streams, in other words, a `KafkaStreams` instance is responsible for monitoring one or more `KStream`, or `KTable`

```
final Topology topology = builder.build();
final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
```

Comment: Welcome. You might be interested in this https://streamthoughts.github.io/azkarra-streams/